# One controller for two scrollviews

Tags: dart, flutter

I have two scrollviews. One nested which has a SliverAppBar, and then a SingleChildScrollView for the rest of my content (as shown in the code below). I then have a controller which controls the opacity of my Floating Action Buttons, when scrolling up and down.

However, the controller only works if I have it on the NestedScroll, and then it only works when scrolling the actual header, and not when scrolling through the rest of the content.

If I add the same controller to the SingleChildScrollView it makes the two views scroll seperatly. Anyone ideas to a fix?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
    body: NestedScrollView(
    controller: _controller,
              headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxScrolled){
                  return <Widget>[
                    SliverAppBar(
              },
              body:SingleChildScrollView(
            ),
```

I have shortned the code to only show the two views.

This is the method where I change the opacity of the FAB's:

```
 void _scrollListener() {
if(_controller.position.userScrollDirection == ScrollDirection.reverse){
  setState(() {
    _hideFAB = true;
  });
}

if(_controller.position.userScrollDirection == ScrollDirection.forward){
  setState((){
    _hideFAB = false;
  });
}
```

}

Here is a GIF showing that the FAB's only change when scrolling within the SliverAppBar: [GIPHY](https://media.giphy.com/media/7TeORDuFyHFJXpwi6E/source.mp4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by using a `CustomScrollView` instead of `NestedScrollView` and then changing my `SingleChildScrollView` with a `SliverList`.

Answer (score 0):

Use **ListView** instead of `SingleChildScrollView`,
put rest of content into ListView

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
    body: NestedScrollView(
    controller: _controller,
              headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxScrolled){
                  return <Widget>[
                    SliverAppBar(
              },
              body:ListView(
            ),
```

Comment: Tried changing to a ListView, however this made no difference. Still no change in the opacity of the FAB's when scrolling further down than the SliverAppBar.

Comment: I would guess I need to add another controller or something to the ListView, however if I try to do this, I then have to scroll the SliverHeader and Listview seperatly

Comment: Fixed it with a Sliverlist instead. But thanks for the answer.